# System.FormatException issue with an Index

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatexception

I have a rather long set of code which is designed to sort climate data. However, I am currently facing an issue where the code throws a System.FormatException giving me the error explanation:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Climate_Sorting_Application_2._0
{
    public class ClimateRecord
    {
        public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
        public int StationId { get; set; }
        public double RainFall { get; set; }
        public double Sun { get; set; }
        public double TMax { get; set; }
        public double TMin { get; set; }
        public double AF { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0,-15:MMMM yyyy}{1,4}{2,8:F4}{3,8:F4}{4,8:F4}{5,8:F4}{6,8:F4}{7,8:F4}",
                RecordDate, StationId, AF, RainFall, Sun, TMax, TMin);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        static IList<ClimateRecord> LoadData()
        {
            var result = new List<ClimateRecord>();

            using (var monthRdr = new StreamReader("Month.txt"))
            using (var yearRdr = new StreamReader("Year.txt"))
            using (var afRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_AF.txt"))
            using (var rainRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_Rain.txt"))
            using (var sunRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_Sun.txt"))
            using (var tmaxRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_TMax.txt"))
            using (var tminRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_TMin.txt"))
            using (var afRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_AF.txt"))
            using (var rainRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_Rain.txt"))
            using (var sunRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_Sun.txt"))
            using (var tmaxRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_TMax.txt"))
            using (var tminRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_TMin.txt"))
            {
                string year = yearRdr.ReadLine();
                while (year != null)
                {
                    var recordDate = DateTime.ParseExact(year + " " + monthRdr.ReadLine() + " 01", "yyyy MMMM dd", null);

                      var ws1 = new ClimateRecord()
                      {
                          RecordDate = recordDate,
                          StationId = 1,
                          AF = double.Parse(afRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          Sun = double.Parse(sunRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          RainFall = double.Parse(rainRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          TMax = double.Parse(tmaxRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          TMin = double.Parse(tminRdr1.ReadLine())
                      };
                    var ws2 = new ClimateRecord()
                    {
                        RecordDate = recordDate,
                        StationId = 2,
                        AF = double.Parse(afRdr2.ReadLine()),
                        Sun = double.Parse(sunRdr2.ReadLine()),
                        RainFall = double.Parse(rainRdr2.ReadLine()),
                        TMax = double.Parse(tmaxRdr2.ReadLine()),
                        TMin = double.Parse(tminRdr2.ReadLine())
                    };
                    result.Add(ws1);
                    result.Add(ws2);
                    year = yearRdr.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

> ```
>     static void PrintData(IEnumerable<ClimateRecord> data)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("{0,15}{1,4}{2,8}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}{6,8}{7,8}",
>            "Month/Year", "WS", "AF", "Rain", "Sun", "T-Max", "T-Min");
>
>         foreach (var record in data) Console.WriteLine(record);
>     }
> ```

Above section is where the exception is called. Specifically the Console.WriteLine part.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var climateData = LoadData();

            Console.WriteLine("Printing all data: ");
            PrintData(climateData);

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 1 data:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 1));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 2 data:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 2));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 1 data ordered by rainfall descending:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 1).OrderBy(r => r.RainFall * -1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 8 fields in your format string, but only 7 are filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is missing, see ???:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,15}{1,4}{2,8}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}{6,8}{7,8}",
           "Month/Year", "WS", "AF", "Rain", "Sun", "T-Max", "T-Min", "???");
```

Comment: Ah right. Can't seem to figure out why I have that going on

Comment: Yep it had nothing attached to it. I think its just an extra added on due to the Month/Year thing which are separate earlier on in the coding